# I am trying to write the query attached, but getting the error "multi-part identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql

```
Declare @Vaccine varchar(300)
Set @Vaccine = CASE
WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('105','HBIG','HEPA') THEN 'HEPATITIS'
WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('109','109A','109B','109C','HIN1IM','HIN1IS','FLUID','FLUHD','FLULOA','109QIM','109QIS') THEN 'FLU'
WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('102','104','107','108','MMRDEC') THEN 'MMR'
--WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('105','HBIG','HEPA') THEN 'MISC'
--WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('105','HBIG','HEPA') THEN 'TDAP'
--WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('105','HBIG','HEPA') THEN 'FIT'
--WHEN OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE IN ('105','HBIG','HEPA') THEN 'SCREEN'
ELSE NULL
END

BEGIN
SELECT 
    tEmployee.ID as "Employee Number",
    tEmployee.LastName,
    tEmployee.FirstName,
    tEmployee.BirthDate as "Date of Birth",
    tEmployee.Sex as "Gender",
    tEmployeeWorkDetail.Department
    FROM OHM.ohmuser.tEmployee LEFT OUTER JOIN OHM.ohmuser.tEmployeeWorkDetail on tEmployee.EmployeeID = tEmployeeWorkDetail.EmployeeID
--WHERE tEmployeeWorkDetail.Department = '100801000'

SELECT CASE @Vaccine
    WHEN 'HEPATITIS' THEN
        (SELECT     
            HEPATITS.FLDDATE1 as "Hepatitis Vaccine Date",
            HEPATITS.FLDDATE2 as "Hepatitis Vaccine Date2",
            HEPATITS.FLDDATE3 as "Hepatitis Vaccine Date3",
            IMMUNE.FLDTYPE as "Vaccine",
            IMMTYPE.FLDDESCR as "Vaccine Descr",
            HEPATITS.FLDADM1 as "Hepatitis Given By",
            HEPATITS.FLDMAN1 as "Manufacturer",
            HEPLAB.FLDCOMMENT as "Comments",
            HEPATITS.FLDLOGNUM1 as "Lot #1",
            HEPATITS.FLDLOTNUM2 as "Lot #2",
            HEPATITS.FLDLOTNUM3 as "Lot #3",
            HEPLAB.FLDDATE as "Lab Date",
            HEPLAB.FLDSANTBVAL as "Surface Antibody"
            FROM OHM.ohmuser.tEmployee LEFT OUTER JOIN OHM.ohmuser.HEPATITS ON tEmployee.EmployeeID = HEPATITS.FLDEMPLOYEE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 OHM.ohmuser.HEPLAB ON tEmployee.EmployeeID = HEPLAB.FLDEMPLOYEE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 OHM.ohmuser.IMMUNE ON tEmployee.EmployeeID = IMMUNE.FLDEMPLOYEE INNER JOIN
                 OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE ON IMMUNE.FLDTYPE = IMMTYPE.FLDCODE)

    WHEN 'FLU' THEN
        (SELECT 
            IMMUNE.FLDDATE as "Date",
            IMMUNE.FLDTYPE as "Vaccine",
            IMMTYPE.FLDDESCR as "Vaccine Descr",
            IMMUNE.FLDNOTE1 as "Comments",
            IMMUNE.FLDMANUFACT as "Mfr",
            IMMUNE.FLDLOTNUM as "Lot #",
            IMMUNE.FLDADMIN as "Given By"
            FROM OHM.ohmuser.tEmployee LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 OHM.ohmuser.IMMUNE ON tEmployee.EmployeeID = IMMUNE.FLDEMPLOYEE INNER JOIN
                 OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE ON IMMUNE.FLDTYPE = IMMTYPE.FLDCODE)

    WHEN 'MMR' THEN
        (SELECT 
            IMMUNE.FLDDATE as "Date",
            IMMUNE.FLDTYPE as "Procedure",
            IMMTYPE.FLDDESCR as "Procedure Descr",
            IMMUNE.FLDNOTE1 as "Comments",
            IMMUNE.FLDMANUFACT as "Mfr",
            IMMUNE.FLDLOTNUM as "Lot #",
            IMMUNE.FLDADMIN as "Given By",
            TITER.FLDDATE as "Titer Date",
            TITER.FLDTYPE as "Titer Type",
            TITER.FLDRESULT as "Titer Result",
            TITER.FLDCLINIC as "Clinic",
            TITER.FLDCOMMENT as "Comments"
            FROM OHM.ohmuser.tEmployee LEFT OUTER JOIN OHM.ohmuser.TITER ON tEmployee.EmployeeID = TITER.FLDEMPLOYEE LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                 OHM.ohmuser.IMMUNE ON tEmployee.EmployeeID = IMMUNE.FLDEMPLOYEE INNER JOIN
                 OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE ON IMMUNE.FLDTYPE = IMMTYPE.FLDCODE)
End
End
```

I want the first part of the SQL to print once. If @Vaccine is equal to ‘Hepatitis’ or ‘Flu’ or ‘MMR’ then it should print additional data. However, I am getting an error that says “The multi-part identifier "OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE" could not be bound.” What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see a SELECT in your first section.

Answer (score 0):

The message is basically saying OHM.ohmuser.IMMTYPE.FLDCODE doesn't exist either on any of the SERVER (OHM), DATABASE (ohmuser),  SCHEMA (IMMTYPE), TABLE (FLDCODE). Have a quick check to ensure it does on all.

What I have noticed is that you have prefixed all your tables with "OHM.ohmuser". I'm assuming that this is a stored procedure and its in the same database "OHM.ohmuser". Hence, you should be able to remove all instances of it making your code more readable and less prone to error.